# Referencing with bibDesk in LYX

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I was trying to insert a bibliography which I created in BibDesk.  However, when I insert the bibliography(.bib) in Lyx from 'Insert', and compile it the reference list is empty.  Does someone know what's going wrong please?

Comment: I don't know LyX, but did you run `bibtex` or `biber`?

Comment: I used bibDesk to generate a .bib file

Comment: I don't know how LyX works, but usually, one has to run successively (PDF)LaTeX, BibTeX (orBiber), LaTeX, LaTeX, to resolve all the cross-references.

Comment: @Bernard LyX runs BibTeX/Biber automatically. user2541516: You need to cite something for it to appear it the reference list, have you done that?

Answer (score 3):

I use LyX with BibDesk smoothly. Your question is a bit short on details so I'll just go over the obvious things. Make sure there are no spaces in the path/filename. You need to insert in your LyX document a bibtex pipe (Insert/List TOC/BibTex Bibliogrpahy. You then need to tell it where to find your .bib file, i.e., the bib database you maintain with BibDesk. Then, you send your bibliography entries directly from BibDesk: You place the curser in the location in your LyX document where you want the reference to appear, and then you go to BibDesk, right-click on the bib item you want, and choose "send to lyx". If you then hit CTRL-R (or CTRL-D) from LyX, then you should see the references appearing. Remember that BibDesk does not auto-save, so you need to manually save if you are adding bib items on the fly. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that when you choose the content on the "bibliography" you choose "all cited references" but have not cited (insert-citation) any of them.

If you want to show all references regardless of whether citing them or not, just choosing "all references" for the content.